Sci-fi horror movie featuring bipedal insect/monster/alien
After watching Terra Formars, I remembered about this movie that I watched long time ago. My memory is extremely vague about this movie. 
These are about the movies :

I watched it probably around 2000's. So the movie is released probably around 80's/90's
It's in English and probably made in America.
The Genre is Sci-fi horror.
Not animated.

These are about the only scene come to my mind:

The monsters/aliens are bipedal. Probably an insect and quite intelligent
The protagonist (a man) is trapped in a facility. There are a lot of monsters outside the facility.
The facility could be on earth or another planet or dimension (not really sure)
The man is trying to come back from the facility. He is trying to fix the device that can transport? him back.
The background of this scene is black with a lot of electricity striking (a thunderstorm?).

Well, that's all what I remember.

Fire in the sky, or The Arrival.

I haven't see full both movies suggested.But, The trailer is not ring a bell.

The scene that I describe is crucial. Although my description is not 100% correct. and the monster don't have to be an alien. Maybe a creature created in a lab or somethhing

Sounds similar to Pitch Black (2000).

A commercial transport ship and its crew are marooned on a planet full of bloodthirsty creatures that only come out to feast at night. But then, they learn that a month-long eclipse is about to occur. 


The aliens are bipedal  (they do have wings as well) and share at least some similarities with insects.
It's an alien planet
There is a research facility where the characters are staying for a while. They are also trapped inside the wreckage in another scene.
Because of the eclipse most of the latter half of the movie is very dark.
The characters are trying to transport energy cells from the wreckage to an escape vessel, so that they can escape from the planet.


No, It's not Pitch Black.

To me bipedal insect horror movie automatically means Mimic.
The creature does kinda looks like the ones in Terra Formars.
The only other movie i can think of is the terribly bad Starship Troopers 2 and it match very few of your criterias (some facility being surrounded with insects)

Sounds unlikely to me since Mimic stars Mira Sorvino (a woman) and from what I remember is primarily set in the New York subway.

I do agree with you, but memories can be vastly altered in 15 years. I can easily believe that the author is mixing at least two movies with his story.
I can find elements of Screamers to in his description (very smart  insectoids aliens robots , need to go to ship to go back to earth, the electricity and lasers at the end of the moviein a kinda dark place, and almost every set of th e movies looks like abandonned facilities).
But i doubt it's Screamers he is referencing to

Could also be one of the sequels of Mimic. Or a totally different movie. Maybe one of this list : http://www.imdb.com/list/ls000042333/

I haven't see Mimic and the trailer is not enough. It's not starship trooper 2
